# Unity Round (Circle) Buttons

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, gui, mouse

I have been using Unity and C# scripting now for the past 2 or 3 weeks. So yeah I am very new to Unity and C#.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make a round (circle) button without using a rect.

The problem I have now, I am using a 2d sprite to make the button appear round, however when you hover or click within the rect, it still works.

I saw this asset in the asset store called [Alpha Raycaster](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/alpha-raycaster-28601).

I cannot afford to pay for it right now so I was wondering if there is a free alternative to the Alpha Raycaster for now.

Does anyone know how we can solve this issue? I obviously only want the button to function when the user hovers or clicks within the sprite and NOT on the alpha surrounding the sprite.

Comment: Does a CircleCollider2D not do the job for you?

Comment: @DMGregory I dont know how to implent it. Because I have added the circle collider to the button. but I dont know what else to do after that.

Comment: This may help you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/non-rectangular-button-with-adequate-input-detection-area.263537/ They use `ICanvasRaycastFilter` interface to override where raycast hit and where doesn't.

Comment: Try showing us how you've implemented your button so far. There's more than one way to make a button in Unity, so we'll need to see what you're doing to know where to plug in changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is much simpler than it seems.  Unity has functionality built in for this.

```
theButton.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold = 0.5f;
```

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold.html)

What this does is only register hits from the raycast if the pixel hit has an alpha of 0.5 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

There is one easy way that only works for round Shapes.
In your Button callback you could test the distance of the mouse from the center of the button against the radius of the button and only trigger the click or hoover effect when it is within the buttons radius.

But since you are new, maybe focus on making some gameplay rather than the button design. While a good look and feel are important, i believe a working game will motivate you more. Try focusing on what you can do, instead of what you can't.

Comment: Yeah thanks I  was looking at doing the math for that. Even though it may work for the actual functionality, it still doesnt affect the hover state, so unless i change the actual hover animation. then that will be okay. What about the circle collider 2d. Do you know how I could use that maybe becuase saw a post about the circle collider

Answer (score 1):

YES! THANK YOU @trollingchar.

I added the code to a script and attached the script to the button.
that is exactly the functionality i was looking for.

check out the link to the code:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/none-rectangle-shaped-button.263684/#post-2146709

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class RaycastMask : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter
{
    private Sprite _sprite;

    void Start ()
    {
        _sprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
    }

    public bool IsRaycastLocationValid(Vector2 sp, Camera eventCamera)
    {
        var rectTransform = (RectTransform)transform;
        Vector2 local;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform) transform, sp, eventCamera, out local);
        // normalize local coordinates
        var normalized = new Vector2(
            (local.x + rectTransform.pivot.x*rectTransform.rect.width)/rectTransform.rect.width,
            (local.y + rectTransform.pivot.y*rectTransform.rect.height)/rectTransform.rect.width);
        // convert to texture space
        var rect = _sprite.textureRect;
        var x = Mathf.FloorToInt(rect.x + rect.width * normalized.x);
        var y = Mathf.FloorToInt(rect.y + rect.height * normalized.y);
        // destroy component if texture import settings are wrong
        try
        {
            return _sprite.texture.GetPixel(x,y).a > 0;
        }
        catch (UnityException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Mask texture not readable, set your sprite to Texture Type 'Advanced' and check 'Read/Write Enabled'");
            Destroy(this);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

for those that are too lazy to follow the link :)
here is the code snippet.

It was posted by @senritsu

if i could hug you right now i would :)